# Maven run different classes without configuration

Tags: java, maven

I want to run specific classes from the command line. I have 10 or more classes that need to be run.

I tried:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.company.xxxx" -Dexec.args="arg0"
```

Error is:

```
The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java are missing or invalid
```

Then I found this solution:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <configuration>
              <mainClass>com.soebes.test.First</mainClass>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>second-cli</id>
            <configuration>
              <mainClass>com.soebes.test.Second</mainClass>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>third-cli</id>
            <configuration>
              <mainClass>com.soebes.test.Third</mainClass>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

and I can run them like :

```
mvn exec:java@second-cli
```

and so on..

Do I have to add all the classes to the pom.xml? Is there any other way to run them without configuration?

Comment: This is a rather unusual requirement. Could you explain more background? What do these classes do? Why to you want to call them during the build?

Comment: @JFMeier I will run those classes from a spring boot project. that's why I need to compile them and according to the request that is received by spring boot, I will run one of them. All of them are web crawlers. Every class has its own main method. Basically, I will get a request as "run xxx.java", I will compile the project, Then finally I will run xxx.java. But right now I don't know how to do it without configuration and I do not want to add all the crawlers' main methods to the pom.xml

Comment: First of all, why don't you compile the project beforehand? Why do you want to compile it _after_ the request? Secondly, why does the project not have just _one_ main class and a parameter that specifies which crawler to run?

Comment: I cannot do it, because that will make the project much more complicated. Is there any way to run only one of them ?

Comment: IMHO, having 10 main classes makes the project complicated. Having one would make it much simpler.