# How to run different Java classes with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, emacs, execution

Pretty much the title question. I have found several other questions on SO, but they're a bit old and I don't know if there's a new solution worth mentioning.

So I am working with the [tutorials](https://developer.lightbend.com/guides/akka-quickstart-java/) for the Java Akka library. I have copied the project and opened it with Emacs. Right now, the main class to be run is specified in the `pom.xml`:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <executable>java</executable>
    <arguments>
      <argument>-classpath</argument>
      <classpath />
      <argument>com.example.AkkaQuickstart</argument> <!-- HERE -->
    </arguments>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But **what if I wanted to have two or more main classes, and run them separately as in IntelliJ**? Now, this is not as much an Emacs question as a Maven one, but suggestions are welcome.

- Should I specify the main class from command line? Using `exec:java` or `exec:exec`? What parts of `pom.xml` should I comment out?
- Should I use a workaround like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60815166/maven-run-different-classes-without-configuration)?
- By the way, since I want something similar to IntelliJ, do you know how IntelliJ actually does this?

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: You could use `profiles` for this.

Comment: What is the purpose of more than one main class? Why not have one main class that calls all the other classes? You could distinguish them by command line parameters.

Comment: Note that there are better IDEs for java and maven than emacs. Generally you need all the help you can get

Comment: I strongly recommend to start using IntellIJ and learn how to use it...it will boost your productivity ... and no that's not possible with Emacs nor Vim etc.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51504549/run-multiple-classes-using-maven

Comment: @RobAudenaerde you mean Spring profiles? I could, but I never used Spring and if possible I want to keep everything as simple as possible.
@JFabianMeier Akka is targeted at multi process applications, that's why I need multiple `main`s. Writing a dispatcher is a possibility, but I wanted to know what was the mechanism used by IntelliJ
@mazi thanks! So I suppose that's still the preferred way. Kudos!
To the others: yes, I know that IntelliJ is still the state of the art for Java development (and I like it!). I wanted to know what was its mechanism to replicate it in Emacs

Comment: No I mean maven profiles https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html